# node -v doesn't work without ./

Tags: linux, node.js, failed-installation

I used

```
cd /usr/local   
tar --strip-components 1 -xzf /usr/save/node-v4.2.1-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

to install NodeJS on my machine. Then I updated `npm` to the latest version. When I execute `node -v`, there is no output. I need to use `./node -v` to see the version of the package. I tried to create hard and symbolic links to /usr/bin/node but have to use ./node.

How do I correct the mistake?

Comment: What happens if you type `which node` or `which npm`? Also, I bet `./node -v` only works from the `/usr/save` folder. I would remove the .tar.gz and download using your package manager and/or brew.

Comment: The package doesn't work as intended when installed from package manager.

Comment: /usr/local/bin/node & npm

Answer (score 0):

The `node` binary was installed in the `/usr/local` directory as per your installation. This means the `node` binary is in the `/usr/local/bin` directory as opposed to the `/usr/bin` which you linked to.

You'll need to add `/usr/local/bin` to your `$PATH`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

You'll also need to add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.

I'll recommend you install `node` via a package manager.

Comment: NodeJS from package manager doesn't install correctly and faced the similar problem.